# How to install a "locale" to be used in php on a osx machine?

Tags: php, apache, macos, locale

I'm developing a website that needs multilingual support. I am trying to use locales in php but a certain locale (es-CO) is not available in my development machine. It is on my hosting server. I've researched on how to add new locales but can't find how or where to get the new locale files. Should this be installed in the OS, on apache or on php? and where can I get these files? in linux i've found that running sudo-apt get language-pack-es-base does this but no idea how to do this in osx. Knowing how to do it in windows should come in handy also.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As @alombarte said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991603/add-a-locale-in-mac-osx) Just type in Terminal

```
cd /usr/share/locale
sudo cp -R es_ES es_CO
```

check by executing locale -a OR

```
locale -a | grep es_
```

Comment: This approach (which simply _copies_ an existing locale), stopped working in macOS 10.11 (El Capitan), when [SIP](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) was introduced.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm correct you can install more locales using the Max OS X install disk