# Set LC_COLLATE and LC_CTYPE on MacOs

Tags: database, postgresql, macos, locale, psql

I am trying to create a new database in postgresql with the following script.

```
CREATE DATABASE test
OWNER dba
TEMPLATE template0
ENCODING 'UTF-8'
LC_COLLATE 'nb_NO.UTF-8'
LC_CTYPE 'nb_NO.UTF-8'
```

When I run the script I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid locale name: "nb_NO.UTF-8"
```

I can see that on Linux Based Systems there is a command called

```
locale-gen
```

But I can't find something similar for macOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this ERROR, it is clear that Locale nb_NO.UTF-8 is not present on your MacOS.

And for the command to check the locales on you macOS please use the below command.

```
locale -a
```

Comment: But how can I then add the new locale?

Comment: You may try this to see if this work in your case:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991603/add-a-locale-in-mac-osx

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? If yes will you please mark the answer as accepted for the record?